# Understanding Noether's conservation law for a left-invariant metric on a Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, calculus-of-variations

I'm trying to understand the equation on the bottom of page 71 in Robert Bryant's [notes](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ebryant/ParkCityLectures.pdf) on Lie groups and symplectic geometry. It illustrates Noether's famous theorem on symmetries (or rather conservation laws) of Lagrangians so I will need some notation before posing my doubt.

**Notation:** Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $L :TM \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function (Lagrangian). A curve $\gamma :[a,b]\to M$ is called $L$-critical if for any smooth variation $\Gamma_s$ of $\gamma$, we have that $0$ is a critical point of the function
$$
s \mapsto \int_a^b L\left(\frac{\partial \Gamma_s(t)}{\partial t}\right)dt
$$

If $x$ denotes a set of local coordinates on $M$, then $(x,p)$ will denote the canonically induced coordinates on $TM$. There is a $1$-form $w_L$ on $TM$ which is uniquely defined by the requirement that, locally, it should have the form
$$
w_L=\sum \frac{\partial L}{\partial p_i} dx_i.
$$

**Theorem: (Noether)** Let $X$ be a vector field on $M$ with local coordinates $\sum a_i(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ and with local flow $\alpha_t$ on $M$. Say that the Lagrangian $L$ is invariant under the derivative $d\alpha_t$, that is, $L\circ d\alpha_t = L$. Let $\widetilde{X}$ denote the vector field on $TM$ induced from the flow $d\alpha_t$. Then the function $w_L\left(\widetilde{X}\right)$ on $TM$ is constant on the curve $d\gamma$ for $\gamma :[a,b] \to M$ which is $L$-critical. $\square$

Note that, when we compute with the local coordinates $(x,p)$, we have
\begin{equation}\label{wL(X)}\tag{1}
w_L\left(\widetilde{X}\right)(x,p) = \sum \frac{\partial L(x,p)}{\partial p_i} a_i(x).
\end{equation}

**Notation for Lie groups:** Now we let $G$ be a Lie group and let $\{\omega_i\}$ be a basis of left-invariant $1$-forms on $G$. Let $L: TG \to \mathbb{R}$ be the Lagrangian
$$
L = (w_1)^2 + \dots + (w_n)^2.
$$
Let $\{A_i\}$ be a basis for $T_eG$ and let $Y_1$ be the right-invariant vector field on $G$ whose local flow is given by $\alpha_t(x) = \exp(tA_1)x.$ Now if $X_i$ is a left-invariant vector field given by the flow $(t,x)\mapsto x\exp(tA_i)$, then one can compute
$$
d\alpha_t(X_i(x)) (f) = X_i(x) \left(f\circ \alpha_t\right) = \frac{d}{ds}\bigg|_{s=0} f\circ \alpha_t\left( x \exp(sA_i)\right) 
= \frac{d}{ds}\bigg|_{s=0} f\left(\exp(tA_1 x \exp(sA_i)\right) = X_i(\alpha_t(x))(f).
$$
Thus, $d\alpha_t(X_i) = X_i$ and so $L\circ d\alpha_t =L$ which shows that we can apply Noether's theorem with $Y_1$ as the infinitesimal symmetry. Thus the function $ w_L\left(\widetilde{Y}_1\right)$ is constant on the derivatives of $L$-critical curves.

**Question:** How do I see the truth of the formula
\begin{equation}\label{ques}\tag{2}
w_L\left(\widetilde{Y_1}\right) = w_1(Y_1)w_1 + w_2(Y_1) w_2 + \dots + w_n(Y_1) w_n?
\end{equation}
In particular, what coordinates do I use in formula (\ref{wL(X)}) to see formula (\ref{ques}). In general, the vector fields $X_i$ don't commute under the Lie bracket so they are not integrable to a set of coordinates.

**Attempt:** I'm thinking about using the chart $(x_i) \mapsto  \Pi \exp(x_i A_i)$ near the identity and the induced coordinates on $TG$. Then, at least at points of the form $(0,p)$, formula (\ref{ques}) seems plausible. But I don't know what happens at other points.

Plas healp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author pointed out that this follows from the general considerations in the example preceeding my question -

We have a Lagrangian induced by a Riemannian metric. In local coordinates we can denote this by
$$
L(x,p) = \sum_{i,j} g_{ij}(x) p_i p_j
$$
where $[g_{ij}(x)]$ gives a symmetric nonsingular matrix for every $x$. In particular, we have a quadratic form, denoted as $G_x(\cdot,\cdot)$ on every tangent space $T_x(M)$.

Moreover, we can compute
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
w_L(x,p) = \sum_i \frac{\partial L(x,p)}{\partial p_i} dx_i &= 
\sum_i\left(2\sum_ug_{iu}(x)p_u\right)dx_i.\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Thus, if $Y= \sum_i a_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is a vector field on $M$ with $\widetilde{Y}$ the associated vector field on $TM$ as written in Noether's theorem, we see that formula $(1)$ in the post becomes
\begin{equation}
w_L\left(\widetilde{Y}\right)(x,p) = \sum_i \frac{\partial L(x,p)}{\partial p_i} a_i(x)
= 2\sum_{i u} g_{iu}(x)p_u a_i(x) = 2G_x(Y(x), p).
\end{equation}
That is, the $w_L\left(\widetilde{Y}\right)$ is the function on $TM$ that is obtained by simply plugging in $Y$ to one of the coordinates of the quadratic form $G$!!

Formula (2) in the post then becomes apparent (upto the constant $2$) by noting that if we use the frame of left-invariant vector fields, the matrix inducing the quadratic form (from the post) is the identity matrix.